# Simplify this Logic Function?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Have a Hardware Lab to do, and I need to reduce the following function before I actually hook it up to the Logic Trainer.

(not ac) + (abc) + (a not c)

Or:

> $\lnot (a \land c) \lor (a \land b \land c) \lor (a \land \lnot c)$

Thanks!

Comment: Reduce to what? Is there a specific form you are looking for?

Comment: If we can interpret the second form as a formula of *propositional logic*, you can : *(i)* rearrange it as $(\lnot (a \land c) \lor (a \land \lnot c)) \lor (a \land b \land c)$. But *(ii)* $\lnot(a \land c) \lor (a \land \lnot c)$ is equivalent to $(a \land c) \rightarrow (a \land \lnot c)$ and this, by truth-tables, is equivalent to $\lnot c$. So, the result is $\lnot c \lor (a \land b \land c)$ that is *(iii)* $c \rightarrow (a \land b \land c)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That reduction is not correct. If $a=b=0$ and $c=1$, the original is $1$ while your result is $0$.

Comment: @James Herbert - you are right !

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reduction: $\neg(a\wedge c)$ equals to $(a\wedge\neg c)\vee(\neg a\wedge c)\vee(\neg a\wedge\neg c)$. But $(a\wedge\neg c)$ already exists at your formula, so you can just ignore it and have $\neg(a\wedge c)\vee(a\wedge b\wedge c)$

Answer (score 0):

¬(a∧c) = ¬(a∧c)

so ¬(a∧c)∨(a∧b∧c)∨(a∧¬c) = ¬(a∧c)∨(a∧b∧c)

for a∧c = x

-x ∨ (x∧b)

---

which means

if b = 1  answer is -x

if b = 0  answer is 0

= b∨-x

in other words

-x ∨ (x∧b) = (-x∨x) ∧ (-x∨b)

---

= 0 ∧ (-x∨b)

= -x∨b

= ¬(a∧c)∨b

Answer (score 0):

$\neg(a \wedge c)\lor(a \wedge b \wedge c)$ is not equivalent to the formula in question. The assignment $v$ with $v(a)=v(c)=1, v(b)=0~$ falsifies $\neg(a \wedge c)\lor(a \wedge b \wedge c)$, but verifies the original formula.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused. Of course v doesn't verify the original formula either.